# "npm ERR! unexpected end of JSON input near" while creating a new react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[enter image description here][1][npm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKPsT.png)

I am trying for so many times to create a app in react but every time the CMD showing an ERR!

here is code :
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.476]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Sumit>E:
The system cannot find the drive specified.

C:\Users\Sumit>D:

D:>React js
'React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:>react js
'react' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:>React js
'React' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

D:>create-react-app my_react

Creating a new React app in D:\my_react.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/react (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-01T14_33_43_496Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my_react / from D:\
Done.

D:>create-react-app my-react-app

Creating a new React app in D:\my-react-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...Y3hEcJW8se9P4K6+GYGu9'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-01T14_34_57_334Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-react-app / from D:\
Done.

D:>create-react-app new-react

Creating a new React app in D:\new-react.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gAAwSQP/RpJCkm/rgw8jt'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-01T14_38_28_735Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting new-react / from D:\
Done.

D:>npm create-react-app my-react-aplication

Usage: npm

where  is one of:
    access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
    clean-install, clean-install-test, completion, config,
    create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, dist-tag, docs, doctor,
    edit, explore, fund, get, help, help-search, hook, i, init,
    install, install-ci-test, install-test, it, link, list, ln,
    login, logout, ls, org, outdated, owner, pack, ping, prefix,
    profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart, root,
    run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
    stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
    uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
    whoami

npm  -h  quick help on 
npm -l            display full usage info
npm help    search for help on 
npm help npm      involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Users\Sumit.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm  --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@6.14.4 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

D:>npx create-react-app my-react

Creating a new React app in D:\my-react.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...gAAwSQP/RpJCkm/rgw8jt'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sumit\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-06-01T14_54_02_126Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting my-react / from D:\
Done.

D:>

Comment: Can you provide some code and the error message in the post please. This will help to understand things better.

Comment: try deleting package-lock.json and then type "npm cache clean --force" in cmd and then try npm install

Comment: @MrPickles  I updated some code for your concern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you didn't install npm in general mode, it should better you do it with this comment in the root with the command
*`npm install -g`*
, or if you did it before you need to update it with the command 
*`npm update [-g]`*

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that you can do that might possibily help you resolve the issue you are facing.

#### 1.If you are on a slow internet connection you might have to increase the timeout from 30s to 60s by adding this to your .npmrc file:

```
timeout=6000
```

You can find the .npmrc file at the path:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
```

#### 2. This issue might be due to npm version mismatch, you can try to install the latest npm version by typing the following command in cmd:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: But, how can i increase that timeout in  npmrc file

Comment: @SumitSarkar go to this location: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm you will find a npmrc file edit it and add timeout=6000 to the bottom of the file